# How to insert composite primary key using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aiopg

When I try to insert the composite primary key connection returns 0 rows:

```py
CompetitionRound = sa.Table('CompetitionRound', metadata,
                            sa.Column('CompetitionId', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('Competitions.Id'), primary_key=True),
                            sa.Column('RoundId', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('Rounds.Id'), primary_key=True))
...
competition_round_insert = await conn.execute(
    CompetitionRound.insert()
                    .values(CompetitionId=competition_id,
                            RoundId=round_id))
competition_round_row = await competition_round_insert.fetchone()
```

Seems like it is not possible to insert the composite primary key as values ... but how to insert key in such case ?
Unfortunately I have not found some example in SQLAlchemy documentation ... (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of the documentation, SQLAlchemy only implicitly returns `autoincrement` primary keys, which composite PKs specifically are not:

[autoincrement](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement)

> The autoincrement flag now defaults to "auto" which indicates autoincrement semantics by default for single-column integer primary keys only; for composite (multi-column) primary keys, autoincrement is never implicitly enabled; as always, autoincrement=True will allow for at most one of those columns to be an “autoincrement” column. autoincrement=True may also be set on a Column that has an explicit client-side or server-side default, subject to limitations of the backend database and dialect.

[inserted_primary_key](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.inserted_primary_key)

> Note that primary key columns which specify a server_default clause, or otherwise do not qualify as “autoincrement” columns (see the notes at Column), and were generated using the database-side default, will appear in this list as None unless the backend supports “returning” and the insert statement executed with the “implicit returning” enabled.

Meaning you probably want to use [an explicit returning clause](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/dml.html?highlight=returning#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.returning) on your insert. Not that I really see the point though, you obviously have the relevant values since you inserted them.